# How to sort random elements of an array efficiently so that similar items appear together

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, enums

I'm starting to get myself into algorithms and I need help solving this kind of problem.

**Task set:**

> An array contains sheep and goats in random order. Write a possibly
>   fast method to rearrange the array, so that all goats are at the
>   beginning and all sheep are at the end of the array. Consider the case
>   when all animals are the same kind.

```
public class Sheep {

   enum Animal {sheep, goat};

   public static void main (String[] param) {
      // for debugging
   }

   public static void reorder (Animal[] animals) {
      // TODO!!! Your program here
   }
}
```

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: How about `animals.sort()`? That's possibly fast.

Comment: @Kevin - Thats probably O(n*log n), this can be done in O(n) time.

Comment: @Ott Ramst If you are starting to get into algorithms I would suggest you actually try to provide at least a straw man's solution or your attempt and then seek help on improvising. We are here to help. Asking others to solve the problem in this way will only stop you from getting yourself into algorithms.

Comment: @bhantol Yeah, I know this. But I just want to see what and how other people think because it's frankly a little confuzing for me. But I will get to it.

Comment: -1 The OP doesn't seem to have tried anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if order of the sheep or goats dont matter then any sorting algorithm is slower then a single pass algorithm that just sticks sheeps and goats at opposite ends of a list.

An example of this would be something like a double ended queue or a `dequeue`:

Some Pseudo code:

```
 Dequeue<animal> myQ;
 for(int i = 0; i < animalList.length; i++){
     if(animalList[i].name == "goat") myQ.push_front(animalList[i]);
     else myQ.push_back(animalList[i]);

 }
```

This algorithm is thus `O(n)` with `O(n) extra space` rather then sorting `O(nlog(n))` with `O(n)` extra space I.e merge sort or `O(n^2)` with quick sort (amortized `O(nlog(n))` )

This can also be done in place with `swapping` which is `O(n) and no extra space`. Run through the list from the front and from the back were if the front is a sheep swap with the back (if its a goat) i.e:

```
start = 0;
end = animalList.length() -1;
while(start < end){
  if(animalList[start].animal == "sheep"){
    if(animalList[end].animal == "goat"){
        swap(start,end); // This a function that would swap the elements you could do this in the loop as well
        end--;
        start++;
    }else{
      end--;
    }
  }else{
    start++;
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to `push_back`. They will push back themselves.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: He means if you push all the goats to the front, you can leave the sheep alone as you guarantee that all goats are in front of all sheep.

Comment: The first algorithm was a separate list not `in place` so I `would` have to push front and back

Comment: You're right, I didn't look at your code well. That's because the OP's question was referring to a _in place_ sorting, so that's what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Use two pointers, one starting at the beginning and the other at the end.

Increment the beginning pointer until it is positioned on a sheep or meets the end pointer.
Decrement the end until it is positioned on a goat or meets the beginning pointer.
Swap the entries at the two pointers.
Repeat until the pointers meet.

This is O(n) and does not require additional space.

It is essentially the partition process of the quicksort algorithm.

Comment: Sorry, typo.  Will fix!

Comment: Never mind, you should have left it as it was. After all, you're already doing his homework, the least he could do would have been to catch that one by himself ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is alghorithm similar to quicksort, but in your case, it finishes in O(n) time.

You just go from both sides until you find bad animal on both sides. Then you switch them and continue.

```
   public static void reorder (Animal[] animals) {
     int j = animals.length - 1;
     int i = 0;
     while (i < j){
       if (animals[i] == Animal.goat){
         i++;  
       } else if (animals[j] == Animal.sheep){
         j--;
       } else {
         Animal temp = animals[i];
         animals[i] = animals[j];
         animals[j] = temp;
       }       
     }

     return animals;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is one iteration of quicksort algorithm. It is called partition. C++ standard library provides implementation [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition/).